# Is a tcp packet with only FIN flag set valid?

Tags: firewall, tcp

got some packets dropped, but from what looks like legitimate IP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TCP_CLOSE.svg), it is valid. For more information, see Wikipedia's entry on [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) or the original [RFC entry](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt).